# Leader Election LCR

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, distributed-computing

I am trying to implement leader election algorithm in ring topology of 4 nodes. I am implementing LCR algorithm. How should I proceed with electing leader if suppose my node 3 goes down.

Note:- Notes are numbered 1,2,3, and 4. It is a unidirectional ring and each node has information of the nearest node i.e 1 -> 2  , 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4 and 4 -> 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to have only one pointer to the next node, than you would need to detect on node 4 that node 3 is down. Afterwards node 4 will need to send a message, saying that node 3 is down. Node 2 should afterwards act upon this and modify its successor to be node 4 instead of node 3 and the ring is complete again.

You can determine if a node is alive or dead by sending small hello messages, and when you miss few of them (2 or 3) you can assume it's down.

In your example when node 3 goes down during the election it won't matter since it isn't the highest ID anyway. But when we look at an example, when node 4 would die, you also would need to stop the election and restart it.